# -p option of ps

Tags: linux, ps

If one omits the `-p` option in the the `ps` in Linux, it is implied if a number is given.

`man ps` says

```
      123    Identical to --pid 123.
```

and

```
      --pid pidlist
             Select by process ID.  Identical to -p and p.
```

But it still gives a different output:

```
test@debian:~$ ps 26379
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
26379 pts/14   Ss     0:00 bash
test@debian:~$ ps -p 26379
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
26379 pts/14   00:00:00 bash
```

Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your `ps` implementation.

At least with [FreeBSD ps](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3) and [procps ps, which used in Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps):

```
1   UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash.
2   BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash.
3   GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.
```

So when you did:

```
ps 123
```

`ps` assumes that you want BSD-style, and add to output process state `STAT` column and display command args `COMMAND` instead of executable name `CMD`. With `-p 123`, `ps` assumes you want SysV-style.

---

[Mac OSX ps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html) implementation does not document this behavior but behave like FreeBSD `ps`.

---

With many implementations, you can override the default style with [`PS_FORMAT`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3#PS_FORMAT) variable:

```
# SysV style when using dash `-` in arguments
$ ps -p 1
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 ?        00:00:01 systemd

# Force BSD style even using dash `-` in arguments
$ PS_FORMAT=DefBSD ps -p 1
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
      1 ?        Ss     0:01 /sbin/init
```